# how to increase performance of limit ?,1 when the ? is a huge number

Tags: mysql, performance, limit

I have a situation where I need to use a huge number for the limit. For example,

```
"select * from a table limit 15824293949,1";
```

this is....really really slow. Sometimes my home mysql server just dies.

is it possible to make it faster?

sorry the number was **15824293949**, not 38975901200

**Added:**

```
**Table 'photos' (Sample)**

Photos
img_id img_filename
1       a.jpg
2       b.jpg   
3       c.jpg
4       d.jpg 
5       e.jpg
and so on
```

```
select cp1.img_id,cp2.img_id from photos as cp1 cross join photos as cp2 limit ?,1
```

How I get 15824293949?

I have 177901 rows in my photo table. I can get the total # of possible combinations by using

(total # of rows * total # of rows ) - total # of rows)/2

Comment: You mean that without limit this select executes faster?

Comment: You have a table with 38 billion rows?

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // 38 bills rows are generated by cross join

Comment: If you only need one result from a cross join then I suspect you need a different query. You'll have to include it for people here to analyze, we can't divine what you're doing.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you want the nth combination of two images. I'll try to update my answer below with a possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try limiting the query with a `WHERE` clause on a column with an index on it. E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 38975901200 LIMIT 1
```

**Update:** I think perhaps you don't even need the database? You can find the nth combination of two images by calculating something like `15824293949 / 177901` and `15824293949 % 177901`. I suppose you could write a query:

```
SELECT (15824293949 / 177901) AS img_id1, (15824293949 MOD 177901) AS img_id2
```

If you're trying to get them from the natural order that they're in the database (and it doesn't happen to be their img_id) then you might have some trouble. Does it matter? It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // what if I am using a join query? the number of rows is 38975901200  , but I don't have an id that is greater than 301228

Comment: Perhaps you can include the join query in your question?

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // just added my query

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // by the way, the number was 15824293949.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // I am building a photo contest website. Users should see a set of two photos from the database randomly. And the users should not meet a photo that they already met. I think there might be a solution without using a database.

Comment: @Moon: yeah, you probably want a table to keep track of what users have seen what images. Then just pick single images at random, filtering out the ones they've seen before, until you have two they haven't seen. Insert those to keep track for the next time.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // The problem is...I can't randomly choose a set of photos without using limit or rand(). Rand() is too slow and now..limit is slow as well. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Moon: perhaps see [selecting random record from MySQL database table](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) or pick the random number in your application that's making the SQL calls (you'll just need to query the database for the maximum image id to limit your random numbers from 1 to that).

Comment: @WhiteFang34 // I really appreciate your help tonight. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Moon: no problem, hope that helped :)

Answer (score 5):

MySQL has issues with huge limit offsets with MyISAM engine mostly where InnoDB optimizes that. There are various techniques to get MyISAM limit to behave faster, however add EXPLAIN before your select statement to see what's actually going on. 3 billion rows generated from cross join indicate that the issue lies within the join itself, not the LIMIT clause.
If you're interested in how to make LIMIT behave faster, [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) should provide you with enough information.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this problem does not exists for InnoDB?

Comment: @eisberg: I can confirm that it does though to a lesser extent: http://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/

Comment: Note that I haven't said that the problem doesn't exist - it does, but InnoDB optimizes the LIMIT OFFSET due to clustered index and the way it stores certain columns. The trick at explainextended.com for optimizing LIMIT OFFSET is useful for InnoDB, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have this in some sort of script, where the reason you are looking at that specific point is because it is where you left off last.

Ideally, if you also have an auto_increment primary key field (an id), you can store that number. Then just do select * from table where id > last_seen_id limit 1 (maybe do more than 1 at a time :P)

Generally speaking, what you are asking it to do *should* be slow. Give it something to search for, rather than everything with a limit.